# I mounted an iso file on my external hard drive

Tags: mount

I mounted an iso file on my external hard drive, now my hard drive acts like a DVD and shows only the data about iso file. I can't access my data, and they're very important for me.How can I get out my hard drive from DVD and see my data. 
I use terminal in ubuntu 16.04 , I the comment that I used  was(I check my history):

```
sudo mkdir understanding_CD01.iso
sudo modprobe loop
sudo mount ^Cso /media/understanding_.CD01iso -t iso9660 -o loop
```

Please help me.

Comment: How did you mount it? And where?

Comment: I use terminal and but I can't remember the command I used,   I think it was ,sudo mount ^Cso /media/understanding_.CD01iso -t iso9660 -o loop

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full command there.

Comment: please run `history` and see the `sudo mount` command, and enter it into your question

Comment: How did you copy ISO to external drive? Post this: `sudo parted -l` You only need to post external drive unless something about internal drive is also important.

Comment: I can't solve my problem,  and My external hard drive acts like a virtual Dvd, and I can access its own data.  Please help me